# How to convert java class to json format structure without creating object

Tags: java, json, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I need to document multiple microservices api call,so I have a question that how to create json string out of java pojo class directly. I mean say for example ,

MyPojo.java

```
public class MyPojo {
String name;
List<String> address;
public MyPojo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
//setters and getters

}
```

now I need the string json structure of the pojo without creating object of the class.May be same the way swagger api creates json structure of @RequestBody object in web UI.

something like:

```
String jsonStruct=SomeUtil.convertPojoToJson(MyPojo.class)
```

then it should give like:

```
{"name":"string","address":[]}
```

My Try:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import io.swagger.v3.core.converter.ModelConverters;
import io.swagger.v3.core.util.Json;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema;

public class TEst {
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper(); 

    MyPojo o=new MyPojo();
    o.setName("aa");
    List<String> l=Arrays.asList("a","s");
    o.setAddress(l);
    System.out.println(obj.writeValueAsString(o));

}
}
```

actual o/p:

```
 {"name":"aa","address":["a","s"]}
```

required o/p:

```
 {"name":"string","address":["string"]}
```

CONCERN: But I need to create without creating object as in real the pojo is huge and not possible to set all dummy data.

Comment: you can't. in order to get that "a" and "s" in there, that have to be values in the object. a json represents a class, true, but the values in the json represent the values of the instance(s).

Comment: Maps, Sets/Lists would do the trick as well. I used them to create a dynamic model in json representation. You can still use the ObjectMapper. Give it a try and take a look, if the result is what you expect.

Comment: I updated the json. I require only structure not the values.

Comment: @ManuelPolacek I already tried with ObjectMapper but it gives like: {"name":null,"address":null}...address should be [] not null.

Comment: I think you can achieve this with the help of [jackson-module-jsonSchema](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Podam](https://mtedone.github.io/podam/)

> PODAM is a lightweight tool to auto-fill Java POJOs with data. This
>   comes handy when developing unit tests. Thanks to PODAM users now have
>   a one-liner that does all the work them.

Add PODAM dependency in your project

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>uk.co.jemos.podam</groupId>
  <artifactId>podam</artifactId>
  <version>[latest.version]</version>
  <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
</dependency>
```

- Define your `DataProviderStrategy` if you don't want the default (Random data)
- Define `PodamFactory` bean, initialized with the *Data Provider Strategy*
- Use the `PodamFactory` bean in your code

```
 PodamFactory factory = new PodamFactoryImpl();
 MyPojo myPojo = factory.manufacturePojo(MyPojo .class);
 // write it as json
 System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(myPojo));
```

Comment: Thank you man it works as expected...only default data is horrible,proper DataProviderStrategy  example not getting if you have please share. ACCEPTED!

Comment: I'm going to update my question with a `DataProviderStrategy` implementation to get this ` {"name":"string","address":["string"]}` ASAP